# Electron builder always showing white screen after packaging

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've started using Electron today and it's generally confusing me when using electron-builder. Every time I run "npm run dist", it creates a installer and installing that proceeds to give me a executable that is just a blank white screen. Is it because my index.html is inside a "site" folder instead of the main folder?
[Image of dependency (dist is the folder made when building)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEr4C.png)

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "governmentmayhem",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Government Mayhem v2 by harrup and Troxx",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "electron-pack": "electron-builder --win -p always"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.app",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "site/assets/logo.ico"
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      "site"
    ]
  },
  "author": "harrup and Troxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^20.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^23.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "asar": "^3.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
        minWidth: 1280,
        minHeight: 720,
    });

    win.setAspectRatio(16/9)
    win.setMenu(null);
    win.setIcon('site/assets/logo.ico')

    const dir = path.join(__dirname, 'site/index.html');
    win.loadURL(`file://${dir}`);
}

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit();
    }
})

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Comment: Instead of loading the file using `loadURL`, try `loadFile`. That way you don't have to join the path but should be able to simply use `"site/index.html"`. If that works, I can expand that into an answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried that before but I'll try it again. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yep, same problem. It's a white screen.

Comment: I'm gonna remake the dependency cause it's really messy in terms of installed dependencies, so I'll get back to this post if I find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix it by just simply redoing the entire project. Don't know how it's been fixed, but the previous project had many random installed dependencies (electron-packager, url and path). Just attempt to make your project clean I guess.